# ADODB VBA mysql query either gives E_FAIL or truncates data

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, adodb

I am using ADODB to query an SQL database. Many of my queries work fine, but one particular query keeps giving problems.

When I run the query, it gives an E_FAIL error. Several articles indicate that if this is the case, the .Cursorlocation should be set to the adUseServer. When I do this, the error indeed disppears. However, with this setting the data gets truncated. Some field in the table only. When I google about that problem, it suggests to set the .Cursorlocation to adUseClient. Kinda frustrating. Anybody who can help with this?

```vb
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With rs
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic
        .CursorType = adOpenStatic
        .ActiveConnection = cn
 End With
rs.Open sqlstring, cn, adOpenStatic

For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, i + 1).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
Next i
ActiveSheet.Range("A3").CopyFromRecordset rs
```

Comment: How much data is returned by this query? If it is a lot, have you tried seeing what happens, if you restrict the data through a where clause?

Comment: Thx for your response. About 100 records and 30 fields per record. This should not be a problem, or?

Comment: I just tested it with only 15 records, still the same problem. I have tried different PageSize's and CachSize's, does not have an influence either. Another piece of information is that I did a trace, it showed that the data arrives truncated from the server.

Comment: Sorry to be slow getting back to you. I am on a business trip. The next thing to test is whether you can loop through all the records in VBA (without sending the data to Excel).

Comment: Thanks, yes I can. i do this to retrieve the headers. See the code: for i = 0 ......

Comment: The data is in the object to be retrieved. In the trace I saw that the data was also abbreviated, so the data does get truncated on the server side.

Comment: Is the truncation the same according to the Cursor.Location property?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. If I change the cursor.location to the server side there is no truncation, but I get the E_FAIL error.